# How to change text to link in google web app?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

So I have spreadsheet with list of all spreadsheets we use for the project.
Simple table in spreadsheet with links to other spreadsheet. I wanted to have it as a website so I create a simple code and deployed. The problem I have is that links are regular text on the website so how could I change them to links?

do you have any ideas how it could be solved?

GAS:

```
  function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index').evaluate();
}
 
function getData(){
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('**********************');
  const srcSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow()-1, 4).getDisplayValues()
 
  return srcValues;
}
 

function include(filename) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(filename)
      .getContent();
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css">
 
    <script>
  
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showData).getData();
 
  function showData(dataArray){
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#data-table').DataTable({
        data: dataArray,
       
        columns: [
          {"title":"File"},
          {"title":"Content"},
          {"title":"Link"},
          {"title":"Contact"}
         
        ]
      });
    });
  }
</script>

  </head>
 
   <body>

<!--- TABLE---->
    <div class="container center">
      <br>
      <div class="row　center">
        <table id="data-table" class="table table-striped table-sm table-hover table-bordered">
          <!-- TABLE DATA IS ADDED BY THE showData() JAVASCRIPT FUNCTION ABOVE -->
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, how about using `render`? In this case, please modify your Javascript as follows.

#### From:

```
columns: [
  {"title":"File"},
  {"title":"Content"},
  {"title":"Link"},
  {"title":"Contact"}
 
]
```

#### To:

```
columns: [
  {"title":"File"},
  {"title":"Content"},
  {"title":"Link", "render": e => `<a href="${e}" target="_blank">${e}</a>`},
  {"title":"Contact"}
]
```

- From your script, I guessed that the column "C" is the hyperlink.

#### Reference:

- [columns.render](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render)

Comment: thanks a lot! It works for me! I guess I was looking for more complicated solution...